# Solver options in Pyomo as long as using the NEOS solvers

Tags: python, solver, pyomo, modeling-languages, neos

I am working on a scheduling problem that is already coded in Pyomo. To solve the problem, I have used the NEOS solver, CPLEX. Now, to test and run some of the instances, I need to call some CPLEX internal options like, mipgap, branching priority, warm-start, solver log, etc. I also tried some functions to do this, but a few of them can work fine in a robust way, specifically, when needs to invoke the solution after the optimization terminates. The method I am currently using is something like this:

```
results = solver_manager.solve(m, solver = "cplex", tee= True, keepfiles=True, logfile = "log.txt", options_string="mipgap=0.1")
```

At the moment, this method can only handle `solver = "cplex"` and `options_string="mipgap=0.1"`. Also, Pyomo documents contain cplex options, but it has not been mentioned (at least I can't find) how those can be applied when one would like to use NEOS. My question is, ***is there any robust way to use CPLEX internal options when it is called by NEOS?***

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing options using a dictionary like:

```
SolverManagerFactory('neos').solve(m, solver='cplex', options={'mipgap':0.1, 'other_option':'other_option_value'})
```

I tested this locally with Ipopt options that I'm more familiar with and it seemed to work. I don't use NEOS regularly so I'm not sure if there is a way to get the full solver log back from NEOS to confirm that specific options were set but I compared the solution and termination condition when running Ipopt locally and through NEOS.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I really had done it, but it made no sense and already throwing some errors.

Comment: @A.Omidi Hi, did you find a way to pass options to neos solvers?

Comment: @Farshid, unfortunately, I cannot find any related and also comprehensive documents for that, but as suggested by the answer, that is a well-known way to do it, you may define an option file and feeding that into the solver, and would hope it works. For mine, it only works for some of the general options.

Comment: @A.Omidi Thanks for your response. Can you please elaborate more on how to define option file and pass it to the solver? O couldn't find anything on the option file either. Thanks.

Comment: @Farshid, The way I have often used is something like what I mentioned in the question. `results = solver_manager.solve(m, solver = "cplex", tee= True, keepfiles=True, logfile = "log.txt", options_string="mipgap=0.1")`. But for example, I never get the log file by that, and this is still unclear for mine.